# Android app to generate a list of String inside a recyclerView from a .txt file

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am learning android and I am trying to create an app that will display all the words from a *.txt file in the form of a recyclerView. Most of the tutorial that I found are hard coding the elements (images, string etc.) that they are going to display. However, my .txt file has lot of words and i cant type all of them in the code (it will take days). Please help.

for my app i have 2 fragments. the first fragment is for listing all the words and the 2nd fragment is to show a sentence with the word when a word is selected.

for creating a recyclerView first I created a class holding the data(if i am not wrong!!)

```
public class showData {
String title;
String content;

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}}
```

i then created an viewAdaptar class

```
public class viewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<viewAdapter.myViewHolder>{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<showData> data = Collections.emptyList();

//inflate layout for recycle view
public viewAdapter(Context context){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent,false);
    myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    showData current = data.get(position);
    holder.holdtitle.setText(current.title);
    holder.holdcontent.setText(current.content);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView holdtitle;
    TextView holdcontent;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        holdtitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        holdcontent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);

    }
}}
```

I want to show the list on the fragment 1
my fragment1 class initially displayed the words in a ListView with the help of 
InputStream class.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private viewAdapter adapterView;

ListListener sentenceActivity;
public interface ListListener{
    public void displayWord(String text,InputStream res);
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try{
        sentenceActivity = (ListListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
    }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //create view of the first fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


    //open the file
    final InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.android_dev_agreement);
    //get each word of the file with the help of the getWord method
    //Set<String> words = getWords(inputStream);
    //variable to link to the listview in the fragment1
    //final ListView myList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    //create an array list for storing all the words processed from the file
    //ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    //add all the words into the ArrayList
    //items.addAll(words);
    //Convert the ArrayList into viewable items that can be added to the listview
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    //populate the listview
    //myList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //set click listener for item in the Adapter array
    /*myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                inputStream.reset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String text = myList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            sentenceActivity.displayWord(text, inputStream);
        }
    });*/
    return view;
}


private Set<String> getWords(InputStream res){
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(res));
    String line;
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>(2000);
    try{
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] wordsOnLine = line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s}]");
            for (String w : wordsOnLine) {
                if (w.trim().length() < 2)
                    continue;
                words.add(w.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException iox){
        words = null;
    }
    return words;
}}
```

the fragment for Listview was this and it successfully generated the list view. But now i want to change it to RecyclerView.

Please suggest how that can be done.

Comment: This a good starting point for learning RecyclerView: [Using the RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview)